# Sign certificate without prompt in shell-script

Tags: openssl, certificate

I'm writing a shell-script to sign certificates using openssl:

```
openssl ca -config "$CONF" -out "$BOXCERT" -infiles "$CSRFILE"
```

However, when running it, openssl always asks whether I want to sign the certificate:

```
Certificate is to be certified until Mar 19 11:50:33 2023 GMT (3653 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:y

1 out of 1 certificate requests certified, commit? [y/n]y
Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
```

I would like the script to run non-interactively in a server. Is there some command-line parameter or configuration file option to tell OpenSSL to sign the certificate and commit it without prompting?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use the `-batch` option of openssl.

eg:

```
 openssl ca -batch -config "$CONF" -out "$BOXCERT" -infiles "$CSRFILE"
```

Comment: if your ca key has pass phrase  then you can also specify it using various options like environment variable and command line password. it will prompt you otherwise. Here is simple command where you can pass pass phrase as part of command *openssl ca -batch -config "$CONF" -passin pass:keypassword -out "$BOXCERT" -infiles "$CSRFILE"*

Comment: Or using `-nodes` to omit encrypting the private key.